# Jest Unit Test for SPFx webpart. Mock and How to get ISPFX context

Tags: typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx

This is my first time involved in the FrontEnd unit test (Sharepoint web part). My problem is I want to write unit tests for the service layer, but I haven't figured out how to retrieve the Sharepoint context to pass into the class constructor.

```js
export class CRUDService implements ICRUDService {
  private _context: any;
  constructor(private context: any) {
    context = this._context;
  }
  sp = spfi().using(SPFx(this.context));
  /*
  Service logic
  */
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing unit tests for SharePoint Framework (SPFx) web parts using Jest, it's common to use Jest's mocking capabilities to simulate different scenarios. Additionally, you might want to mock the SharePoint Framework context (ISPFXContext) to provide a controlled environment for testing.

Comment: Can you explain more about mocking SP context or do you have any examples for it?